# Next Auth - client_id is required, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am slightly confused as to where the disconnect is happening.

> [...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
    secret:process.env.JWT_SECRET
})
```

> .env

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = qwertclientid
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = qwertyclientsecret

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

JWT_SECRET=qwertysecret
```

I am getting the error:

```
error: {
  message: 'client_id is required',
  providerId: 'google',
  message: 'client_id is required'
}
```

If I don't use process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID from the .env file and I use a string, it works as intended. If i try and use it from the .env file I get the above error. I have also tried to use a string and non string in the .env file.

Comment: Try changing the name of your .env file to .env.local (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variable-load-order)

Answer (score 1):

check where the .env file is located. make sure it is in the parent folder

Answer (score 1):

The error suggest that your providers are not able to access env variables.

```
GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
```

Make sure your .env file is in the root directory of your application. And also the name of the variables initialized matches to the variables in the env folder.